# Compile MFC program with VS 2012 running on windows xp

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-xp

I have the VS 2012 on windows 7. I want to build a MFC program which can be run on windows XP. However I received the following error while I moved the exe file to windows XP: “It is not a valid win32 application”.

After exploring on internet, I discovered that I should install [Visual Studio 2012 Update 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2797915) and change the Platform toolset from “Visual Studio 2012 (v110)” to “Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp)”. I also changed the target machine to “MachineX86 (/MACHINE:X86)”.  This time I receive another error while I run the exe file on windows XP: “the procedure entry point initializecriticalsection could not be located in the dynamic library KERNEL32.dll”.

Now I do not know what to do :(. I do appreciate if some can help me :).

Please note that I tried a simple dialog MFC program without adding any code to it.

Comment: When you tried the simple MFC project did it work or fail?

Comment: I didn't even know you cold *target* XP with 2012. I guess the update granted that by popular demand. You mentioned "Please note that I tried a simple dialog MFC program without adding any code to it." and then... nothing. What was the result, or are we to assume it was the same?

Comment: If in the future please do not link to binary downloads. If you **must** provide a link it should be to the description, source code or download page.

Comment: Make sure you have XP SP3. And simply setting the toolset to `v110_xp` should be enough. I've built a much more complex application with VS2012 that had to target XP just by flipping that switch. Worked like a charm. A few people on the VC++ blog did have some problems though, read the comments: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/10357555.aspx Pay attention to the last one by Daniel about `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01`. Also make sure you have the right redistributable installed on the client machine. (Update 1 vs Update 2 makes a difference, it has to be the same version as VS2012.)

Comment: MSDN quote about service packs: "For these operating systems, the supported versions are Windows XP **Service Pack 3 (SP3) for x86**, Windows XP **Service Pack 2 (SP2) for x64**, and Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2 (SP2) for both x86 and x64."

Comment: ta.speot.is: I have the windows xp service pack 3 version 2002. but still have the same problem. I have updated my Visual studio 2012 to the last version as well but still dose not work.

Answer (score 2):

[This is a bug in Visual Studio 2012 Update 2](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783276/vs2012-2-v110-xp-broken-the-procedure-entry-point-initializecriticalsectionex-could-not-be-located-in-the-dynamic-link-library-kernel32-dll). The link has a workaround for Update 2 (although a community sourced one), and Microsoft has this to say:

> **Posted by Microsoft on 06/05/2013 at 16:16**
>
> Yes, this is fixed in Update 3

So your best bet is to roll back to Update 1 or wait for Update 3.

**EDIT** [Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 Release Candidate has been released with "go-live"  licensing](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38832). Caveat:

> **Statement of Support**:
>
> Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 RC and Team Foundation Server 2012 with Update 3 RC are “go-live”. This means that customers can use these builds in production environments. **These are still pre-releases**, so there may be some bugs that will be fixed for the final release. Upgrade from Update 3 RC to Update 3 RTM is supported. In order to upgrade to future releases, the customer must first upgrade from Update 3 RC to Update 3 RTM.

More information is available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/05/07/fix-visual-studio-2012-update-2-breaks-windows-xp-targeting-with-atl-and-or-statically-linking-mfc.aspx).

**EDIT 2** Turns out [rolling back to Update 1 breaks Visual Studio](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/785396/uninstalling-vs2012-update-2-and-repair-of-vs-results-in-atl-files-missing)...

Comment: Still having the same issue despite Update 3 RC

Comment: @tofutim Take a look at the first link. See the comment by simdoc and the workaround by YLzhou. May or may not help.